# django {% url %} tag without parameters

Tags: django

I have a url defined as follows:

```
url(r'^details/(?P<id>\d+)$', DetailView.as_view(), name='detail_view'),
```

In my templates, I want to be able to get the following url: `/details/` from the defined url.

I tried `{% url detail_view %}`, but I get an error since I am not specifying the `id` parameter.

I need the url without the ID because I will be appending it using JS.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What would the purpose be? This URL can't be matched if there is no `id` parameter, so why would you want to create a link to it? Maybe you're trying to solve another problem and your solution just isn't the right one?

Comment: I will append the ID using javascript, but I'd like to have the URL as js variable.

Comment: You could always use the reverse with `id = -1` (which you wouldn't expect to be an ID anyway) and replace the rightmost -1 with the proper ID when you need it.
Seems very hackish to me if you ask me, but always better than defining another URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add this line to your `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^details/$', DetailView.as_view(), name='detail_view'),
```

**or:**

```
url(r'^details/(?P<id>\d*)$', DetailView.as_view(), name='detail_view'),
```

(This is a cleaner solution - thanks to Thomas Orozco)

You'll need to specify that `id` is optional in your view function:

```
def view(request, id=None):
```

Comment: Note: the two urlpatterns will need to have a unique name, so if you name this one "detail_view", rename your original to something like "detail_view_with_id".

Comment: If you're going to modify the view to accept an optional parameter, I think you might as well make the parameter optional: `r'^details/(?P<id>\d*)$'`.

Comment: how do you specify the id parameter in the template `{% url detail_view %}`

Comment: Not really a solution for Class Based views :(